# Fix spacing for right-side y-axis labels with 270 rotation

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I move the y-axis label to the right side of the axes and rotate it by 270˚, the label is not properly spaced relative to the axis border:

```py
ax.yaxis.set_label_position("right")
ax.set_ylabel("latitude", rotation=270)
```

I can fix it visually by setting `ax.set_ylabel("latitude", rotation=270, labelpad=12.0)`, but my experience with Matplotlib is that, in recent versions at least, there's usually a better way to do things than manually setting spacings.

Is there some missing option to request correct spacing? Without setting `rotation=`, the spacing is perfect, so maybe it has to do with re-centering the text relative to the axis of rotation.

[image: Bad spacing between y-axis label and border]

Comment: have you tried using the `tight_layout` option?

Comment: @Ftagliacarne yes, I get the same result with both "tight" and "constrained" layouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also set the vertical alignment "va":

```
ax.set_ylabel("latitude", rotation=270, va="bottom")
```

Comment: For future readers: the `set_ylabel` extra `**kwargs` are passed to `Text`. Related docs: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text and https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/text_alignment.html. I didn't see any documentation of what the default is (I don't think it's in `rcParams`), but it seems to be `bottom` from my quick testing. I don't know why it needs to be set manually when setting `rotation=`.